# What is the name of the school of thought that holds "humans did it"?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, truth, skepticism

My world view is that there is no way to peek behind the curtains of the universe to reveal its *truths*-- whether spiritual, religious, or even scientific.

I don't think the word to describe this is Skepticism because whether or not I can be certain of all truths is not really the question I am trying to ask. It is irrelevant to me whether or not I can truly know that I and the things and around me exist. I simply recognize that all attempts to quantify the workings of the universe are man-made descriptive models that can, admittedly, be extremely accurate at predicting things but can never attain the stamp of universal truth.

The word I've been using to describe myself so far is Anthropocentric in an attempt to denote the idea that every piece of information or knowledge in the world is the product of human minds, but I feel as if Anthropocentrism additionally attributes a certain spiritual significance to humanity that I wish to avoid. I don't want to rule out the possibility that other organisms can develop and share their own systems of world-outlooks. My only admission is that only the ideas of humanity are the ones we have access to so far.

Is there a word for the school of thought and/or philosophy that holds "humans made it all up," or, more broadly, "citizens/inhabitants of the universe made it all up"?

Comment: ...made 'what' up?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for is the scientific method

Comment: Sounds like you're using the opposite of the scientific or philosophical method and forming beliefs for no good reason. I don't think there is a word for someone who jumps to conclusions in his way. A gambler? A pessimist? An anti-philosopher? .A Materialist? An epistemological nihilist?

Comment: PeterJ, it should have gone without saying that even though I did not feel the need to list the reasons why I have formed my views, I certainly have at least some good reasons to hold what I do.

Comment: @MBZKEllisLS - Pardon me if I sounded a bit dismissive. It was the fact that you have formed a belief that seemed anti-philosophical. It's a reasonable speculation but you know already that you do not actually know whether it's possible to 'peek behind the curtain' so why form a belief? It's an odd belief when so many people say they can see behind it but there's nothing to stop you tentatively speculating that they're lying, and nothing to stop you checking the facts for yourself. I think 'epistemological nihilism' may be the term you're after.

Comment: @PeterJ, Another way to re-frame "can't peek behind curtain" is: if it's accessible to human minds (or anyone in universe), humans (or anyone in same collective brain-space) produced it. When people claim to see the other side, I respond: since these ideas are accessible to humans, they are products of humans as well. All academic study of mythology, religion, literature, etc. operates this way. I simply extend this to fields like math and science. I am curious if there is a title for this approach. I don't think EN is it. I make no statement on the know-ability, but on the origin, of ideas.

Comment: @MBZKEllisLS - I can't see a difference in the assumption, which states that all prophets, mystics and sages and me are deluded, but of course you're free to make it. I just feel that making such assumptions is not philosophical best practice. It's never a good idea to close off possibilities arbitrarily. I'm afraid I don't know what your pessimistic position on knowledge is called but it's a common one.  .

Comment: I think it's a bit of a shame that you, and apparently the commenters so far, don't recognise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism An excellent perspective, which has been championed by many great minds, but seems now to have been sidelined by scientism & it's adherents like Dawkins

Comment: You can go back to at least 420BC: "Man is the measure of all things" - Protagoras

Comment: @PeterJ In no way do I think those people, or you, are deluded. I find religious/sacred ideas some of the most profound in history. I am religious to an extent myself. I simply recognize my God is my own/ my religion's creation. This doesn't deny the possibility of God, but is a form of agnosticism: until there is evidence for God, the status quo is humans created religion. (And until there is evidence that the Universe speaks to us, science and math are also human creations--albeit consistent, logical, and great for predictions; but does the universe obey human logic or bestow Truth on them?)

Comment: @CriglCragl, I like Protagoras and I think "Man is the measure of all things" is a nice summary of what I hold, but I'm not sure I'm on board with the rest of Humanism. It seems to buy into the religion-science mutual enmity, but I consider them both equally valid human attempts at quantifying the world. Is this a proper read of Humanism?

Comment: Equally valid? -_^ No it not a 'proper read'. More like: "Know then thyself, presume not God to scan; The proper study of Mankind is Man." There is quite a variety of perspectives within https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_humanism - have a look at the Wikipedia page 'List of noted secular humanists' to see how much! It puts humanity at the centre of our concerns, not priests and gods, or more latterly scientists and science. It can be argued this develops from the Greek perspective, rather than the Abrahamic.

Answer (score 2):

I should say that a variety of **phenomenalism** describes your position. Measure your views against the following possibilities :

> Let us begin by distinguishing several views that have borne the
>    label 'phenomenalism' and noting which of them Lewis held. First,
>    there is *analytical phenomenalism*:
>
> *Statements about physical objects are equivalent in meaning to
>    statements exclusively about sense data (or: ways of appearing, etc.)*
>
> When I speak of phenomenalism without qualification, this is the
>    doctrine I shall have in mind. Next, there is *ontological
>    phenomenalism*:
>
> Physical objects are identical with collections or families of actual and
>    possible sense data.
>
> Ontological phenomenalism is sometimes regarded as merely a
>    "material mode" version of analytical phenomenalism, but I shall
>    regard it as a thesis in its own right.
>
> Lewis also used the term 'phenomenalism' in connection with
>    two other views, which I shall name after their most distinguished
>    proponents. The first of these is *Kantian phenomenalism*:
>
> We know things only as they appear to us, not as they are in themselves.
>
> And the other is *Berkeleian phenomenalism*:
>
> Physical objects are existentially mind-dependent (i.e., they exist only
>    when perceived).

(James van Cleve, 'C. I. Lewis' Defense of Phenomenalism', Philosophy and Phenomenological Research, Vol. 41, No. 3 (Mar., 1981), pp. 325-332 : 325.)

Though the statement of Kantian phenomenalism is brief and in need of elaboration and refinement, it does seem to capture the 'world view' you describe at starting.

Comment: It seems like Kantian phenomenalism is most like what I have in mind. However, all of the other phenomenalisms seem to address the scope of understanding of physical objects. How would these theses (including Kant's) change if we broaden the discussion to include abstract objects as well, like gods, languages (including mathematics and physics etc.), and any other idea or philosophy? Would phenomenalism still hold that such structures are artificial?